# Problem with UV unwrapping. Strange lines occurred

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Recently I decided to create a t-shirt, and on a moment of unwrapping I started to see strange lines on design which is meant to be on a back of a t-shirt.
Screenshots are attached.
Btw I don`t really know what information to provide as Im somewhat new to Blender, so if you need to know something, go ahead.

[image: The screenshot]

Comment: In general it's best not to crop screenshots when you are asking questions and show all the UI including various settings and status bar showing the version of Blender you are using. It doesn't matter much in this case, but since you mentioned you are new to this, it might help with other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Those are pixels at the edges of the image extended.

Change extension mode from Extend to Clip in the image texture node:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot!

Comment: Consider upvoting and accepting as the answer if it was helpful, or downvoting if it isn't helpful at all.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I couldn`t cast an upvote as Im new to this website either and my reputation is lower than 15, but when I will be able to, I will certainly do so!